# JSON & Flex Tree Control

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, flex4.6

I have been tinkering around with XML and the Flex 3 Tree component using XMLList and loading my webservice into the dataprovider of the tree.

However I am having a lot of problems formatting the XML the way I need to for it to display correctly in the tree.

Does the Flex tree support JSON? Will it handle JSON from a C# ASP.NET WebAPI call and populate the tree accordingly? Or is there some pre-data processing I will need to go through?

I have googled this topic to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will support vanilla object with label and children properties (you can also change the configuration of the tree). However it would be better to set up classes and parse the loaded data into this model, since you can have convenience features of Flex like strong typing and data binding.

Comment: Right, this makes sense. However, flex tree only accepts ArrayCollections and XMLList's or XMLListCollections to my knowledge. You're saying I would need to iterate through my json result parsing each item in the collection to a class? I don't quite see where your going with this :p

Comment: You have your Model classes which have two properties necessary: label of type string and children of type mx.collections.IList. Now, the root instance(s) are just stuffed into an mx.collections.IList implementation themselves: function parse(json:String):IList /* of types you defined */ or function parse(vallillas:Object /* or Array, depending of the root JSON object */):IList.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense :) Good to see SOMEONE out there still uses flex even though I'm only using it due to project requirements.